# postgres user's search_path definition varie between co-workers

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Two different co-workers are using `postgres` role to connect to a remote database from a local PgAdmin 4 (v. 6.21).

The `postgres` user is defined as follow:

```
-- Role: postgres
-- DROP ROLE IF EXISTS postgres;

CREATE ROLE postgres WITH
  LOGIN
  SUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  CREATEDB
  CREATEROLE
  REPLICATION
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md5eb8f81...dca697';

ALTER ROLE postgres SET search_path TO siveer_aep, public;
```

The `SHOW search_path;` query returns `'siveer_aep, public'` for one co-worker and `'"$user", public'` fot the other one.

As a result, the schema name is missing from views definition for co-worker having the `'siveer_aep, public'` configuration.

First, why is this configuration different between two co-workers as they are using the same account to connect to the database (same login/password)? Second, is it possible to modify this configuration (using a `SET search_path` query) whithout impacting the `postgres` user for other co-workers?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the connection is to different database clusters. The user may have the same name, but are different, and one may not have the `search_path` setting.

If that is not the reason, check from where the current setting originates:

```
SELECT source FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'search_path';
```

If the setting comes from `ALTER ROLE`, that will return `user`. The result will help solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, the issue was the opposite... I will update my post. My co-worker gave me the wrong information. Anyway, I would like to know the impact of doing a `ALTER ROLE postgres SET search_path TO $user, public;`. Is this going to alter role for all other co-workers?

Comment: Your co-workers connect to different clusters. Changing the setting changes it for everybody who connects as `postgres` to that same cluster. Let's stop here.